# Why cv::format is not giving me the expected result?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with openCV 3.4.0 using C++ with VS 2015 in release mode

I am trying to put text on a specific place in the cv::Mat.

While I am trying this it works:

```
    //int FPS = calculate_FPS(measure_time(false));
    int FPS = 6;
    std::cout << "FPS = " << FPS << std::endl;
    measure_time(true);
    cv::putText(canvas(frame_per_second_area), cv::format("FPS: %d", FPS) , cv::Point(frame_per_second_area.width*0.20, frame_per_second_area.height*0.7), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

And it looks like:

[image]

Until here everything is fine.
However while I trying this way I get bad results:

```
    int FPS = calculate_FPS(measure_time(false));
    //int FPS = 6;
    std::cout << "FPS = " << FPS << std::endl;
    measure_time(true);
    cv::putText(canvas(frame_per_second_area), cv::format("FPS: %d", FPS) , cv::Point(frame_per_second_area.width*0.20, frame_per_second_area.height*0.7), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

It looks like:

[image]

Need to mention that the output to the screen looks good:

[image]

Need to mention #2 - This is the function declaration:

`int calculate_FPS(double elapsed_time_in_ms);`

Comment: Can you try the first variant with `%02d` to see how `06` would look (as opposed to `6`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not calling: `calculate_FPS(measure_time(false));` or not. The actual problem is that you rendering the text repeatedly on the same canvas. I can demonstrate this to you:

### Case 1: Where canvas is not being refreshed before calling the putText:

```
canvas = np.ones((100, 200, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Set the canvas background color as Red.
canvas[:, :] = np.array([0, 0, 255])

for i in xrange(15):
    cv2.putText(canvas, "FPS: " + str(i), (50, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, np.array([0, 0, 0]))
```

[image]

### Case 2: Where canvas is refreshed before calling putText

```
canvas = np.ones((100, 200, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Set the canvas background color as Red.
canvas[:, :] = np.array([0, 0, 255])

for i in xrange(15):
    canvas[:, :] = np.array([0, 0, 255])
    cv2.putText(canvas, "FPS: " + str(i), (50, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, np.array([0, 0, 0]))
```

[image]