# Problem with opencv puttext function in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

[image]When I use the openCV putText() function and the string contains a "2" there is an additional line printed on the image. For strings that do not contain a 2 everything works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Mat image = imread("../test.jpg");

    Point pt1(225, 170);
    Point pt2(456, 546);
    Scalar color(100,200,100);
    rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, color, 2);

    putText(image, "Tag 2", pt1 - Point(0,5), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2);

    namedWindow("Test",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Test", image);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

When the string that I want to display on the image contains a "2" there is an additional line that crosses the string. With other numbers for example "1" everything looks normal.

Comment: What do you mean by saying an additional line ?? I couldnt get the problem. I run your code. There is a text named "Tag 2" on top of the rectangle

Comment: Because you are writing `2` where `1` is already written. Possible duplicate of [Why cv::format is not giving me the expected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755712/why-cvformat-is-not-giving-me-the-expected-result)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk: I added a picture that shows the unwanted line.